# I want to reverse my string as dd/mm/yyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: php, string, date, reverse

I need to reverse my date from **10/21/2016**  to **2016/10/21**
how can I possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime('10/21/2016'));
```

this will helps you

Comment: thank you its working, i have escaped from a dirty problem.

Comment: pleasure to be mine

Answer (score 0):

use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$date = new DateTime('10/21/2016');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```